# Get Start Infinite Scroll with Masonry

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ajaxform

I am beginner for infinite scroll and i never use it. I tried to use this code for my web site. I tried to get alert when scroll to bottom of page up to footer.

My main target is load more HTML contains using ajax and Infinite Scroll when webpage is scroll to bottom of the Wall div. `<div id="wall"></div>`. This div have bottom of the page and above of footer. All HTML contain should be append and in future new content prepend using JQuery.

Javascrip Code:

```
   $("#wall").infinitescroll({
    navSelector: "#next:last",
    nextSelector: "#next:last",
    itemSelector: "#content",
    debug: false,
    dataType: 'html',
    maxPage: 4,
    path: function(index) {
      return "index" + index + ".html";
    }

    }, function(newElements, data, url){
        alert("hi");
    });
```

I tried to this code for begging to get alert when scroll to bottom but it is not working.

Ajax Code:

```
$.post("/php/post.php",
{
    name: "aa",
    city: "bb"
},
function(data, status){
    $("#wall").append(data).masonry().masonry('appended', data, true).masonry("reloadItems").masonry("layout");

});
```

Ajax response data is HTML contains.

How to use Infinite Scroll for JQuery append and prepend more HTML contain using ajax?

Are these HTML contains loading when scroll to bottom of the page or scroll to bottom of the Wall div?

If you know some tutorial website for Infinite Scroll with Masonry please let me know.

Comment: Could you post links to the `infinitescroll` jquery plugin you're using please

Comment: https://github.com/infinite-scroll/infinite-scroll

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, using `debug: true` would reveal any issues that exist with your current setup. Without knowing the html you are using, it is hard to guess, but do all your selectors exist, ie: `#next` and `#content`?

Here is a fiddle that has a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/pgh49735/